# set focus in textbox under ajaxComplete() function causing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, setfocus

I am sending ajax post request while clicking on radio button.

```
 // Get phone number if user selects phone option
    $('.rdoPhone').click(function () {
   if ($('.rdoPhone').is(':checked')) {
       $(".clsEmail_Number").attr('maxlength', '10').focus();
    }
});
```

**Required functionality:** 
Focus should move to below texbox when I send ajax request on clicking radio button ('.rdoPhone')

```
<input type="text" class="clsEmail_Number" id="clsEmail_Number" style="width: 194px"
            name="clsEmail_Number" value="" />
```

But, after ajax request focus() of textbox shifts to first textbox of the page because of below code.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        window.setTimeout(function () { $("input[type='text']:visible:first").focus(); }, 0);
});
```

How can I make sure that my code also work along with $(document).ajaxComplete()

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one solution for the same. But I am also looking for better options (for best option).

Thanks,

Below is the code I used to solve this case.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('.rdoEmail').is(':checked') || $('.rdoPhone').is(':checked')) {
            $(".clsEmail_Number").focus();
        }
        else {
            $("input[type='text']:visible:first").focus();
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting focus in `ajaxComplete` you can try this

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function () { $("input[type='text']:visible:first").focus(); }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have already done that.
But in many cases I need to set focus after ajax request, that is why I wrote under ajaxComplete().
Thanks

Comment: I had one solution but I am looking for better options.
mine is 

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            if ($('.rdoEmail').is(':checked') || $('.rdoPhone').is(':checked')) {
                $(".clsEmail_Number").focus();
            }
            else {
                $("input[type='text']:visible:first").focus();
            }
        }, 0);
    });